# Where to download a specific flight route before the flight?

Tags: commercial-aviation, flight-path

Is it possible to download the flight route before the flight?

I'm interested in a table (or something similar) containing the following data:

```
Timestamp | Coordinates | Human readable location
————————-—+————————————-+—————————————————————————
                       ...
```

This would be quite helpful, so I can follow the airplane progress during the flight, without having internet connection.

Where can I get that from?

Comment: You won't be able to get the actual flight plan since they are not public - why would they be?  You can get a similar possible flight plan from any number of online flight simulation planning sites, [for example this one](http://onlineflightplanner.org/).  However, there are many possible routes between two airports and even the same flight by the same operator will differ from day to day.

Comment: @Simon, I don't know what to think about this [short article](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2011-05-27/private-plane-flight-plans-must-be-public-faa). Is there a possibility to ask for this information supposed to be public (before the flight, if I understand correctly)?

Comment: Well, Repetitive flight plans are actually public in Brazil: http://www.cgna.gov.br/?page_id=148

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I know, you can "decode" certain routes on flightaware.com which will bring up this which may be the closest thing possible to what you want.

[image]

Comment: Yeah but this is "after the fact", not before the flight like the OP is asking. Best bet is to look up the last flight that day between the destination and see that route, it should be close at least.

Comment: @RonBeyer You can find these for flights even before they are planned to like [this.](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/JBU1516/history/20160531/0600Z/KSFO/KJFK/route)

Comment: @SMSvonderTann That is not necessarily the plan. It's just one that's used before.  Actual flight plans are not made public - there is no need for them to be.  Flightaware and other such flights use "after the fact" and guesswork.

Comment: @Simon I don't know if it's guesswork but on Flightaware they don't show up until shortly before the flight and the ones I've tracked usually follow them.

Answer (score 1):

No, such information is not publically available.

It does exist, of course, but in order to obtain it, you would have to know a dispatcher or something similar, and they would have to be willing to disregard their confidentiality agreement.

You could always find the specific flight (flown on a previous date) in a website such as FlightAware of FlightRadar24, and see which route it flew. The route will likely be similar, but not necessarily the same.